# C# to COM define interface

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, com-interface

I have a function in a COM dll that returns a string and takes a string.

I tried this interface, while it compiles, when called it doesn't work. **Not sure how to define it?**

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.HString, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(16)]
        object GetNextOTMOption([In] ref object[] param);
```

Comment: I don't know much about UWP, but are COM methods supposed to return `HString`s in variants? What are the exact language and exact signature of your method?

Comment: Can you tell us what the COM DLL is? If not, can you post the IDL? (Run oleview.exe, part of the Windows SDKs, to extract the UDL.)

Comment: @ Medinoc I am not exactly sure of the language the com .dll is written in, but an educated guess is Microsoft c++. The method signature is [string GetNextOTMOption(string)]

Comment: Pseudocode like "[string GetNextOTMOption(string)]" doesn't help much. If you can post the IDL for the entire interface, we can help you better.